# How to boot off a external optical disk

Tags: usb

I'm installing an OS on an old computer, and I currently have too many DvD's know what to do with, and I want to install Linux on it, so
can I install an os off a USB optical drive, and if I can, how can I?

Comment: This depends on how old the computer is, specifically whether its BIOS is capable of detecting and booting USB storage devices.

Comment: For an good answer, Make and model of PC please?

Comment: My pc is an HP pavilion 13. Note that this is a spare PC and not my current one